# Error in sublist of a list in C#

Tags: c#, .net

I have created a list and then for each member of this list there is another sub-list. The aim is to save some numbers under a condition in a sub-lists.
Here is my code:

```
List<Tuple<int, List<int>>>list_1= new list_1<List<Tuple<int, List<int>>>();

for (int i = 0; i < array_1.Length ; i++)
{
    for (int j = array_2.Length - 1; j > -1; j--)
    {
        if (j > i + 1)
        {
            list_1[i].Item2.Add(j);                    
        }
    }
}
```

where `array_2.Count`and `array_2.Count` are integers.

But I have an error that says :

```
Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection.
```

Could anyone please tell me what I am setting wrong up here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, the immediate cause of the misbehaviour is that `list_1` has *no items* (empty):

```
  List<Tuple<int, List<int>>> list_1= new list_1<Tuple<int, List<int>>>();
```

so the very first attempt to read any item

```
  list_1[i]
```

will throw an *out of range exception*. You have to explictly *add items* into the list (unlike, say, Python):

```
  list_1.Add(new Tuple<int, int>(...));
```

**Edit**: Something like this is expected:

```
  // Add items
  //TODO: what Item1 should be?
  while (i >= list_1.Count)
    list_1.Add(new Tuple<int, List<int>>(0, new List<int>())); //TODO: Item1 = 0?

  // Now it's safe to address list_1[i]:
  list_1[i].Item2.Add(j);
```

Comment: @Saber Jalilzadeh: since you don't know the actual size - you should *add* items whenever you want to increase the size; *list* is not an *array* with *fixed length*; add/insert/remove items whenever you want

Comment: @Saber Jalilzadeh: you have to add to `list_1` itself, not to its *unexisting item* `list_1[i]`

Comment: @Saber Jalilzadeh: well, the principle is the same (you have to add items to `list_1` inself), the implmentation is a bit changed; think over what do you want to put into `Item1` of each `Tuple`

Comment: Thanks a lot. Now it is working for me. I would write it as what I have posted as an answer. The key is this line `list_1.Add(new Tuple<int, List<int>>(i, new List<int>()));
` which I replaced zero with `i`.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to . Here is what I found out is correct:

```
List<Tuple<int, List<int>>> list_1= new list_1<Tuple<int, List<int>>>();

for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
{
    list_1.Add(new Tuple<int, List<int>>(i, new List<int>()));
    for (int j = 5; j >= 0; j--)
    {
        if (j > i + 1)
        {
           list_1[i].Item2.Add(j); 
        }
    }
}
```